# SQL Server 2008 Installation Issues.No checkboxes in Instance Features present

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I m trying to Install SQL Server 2008...there is no check box present in Instance Features.Image link is present below.

Please help me...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkPHV.png

Comment: Are you running it with administrator privileges?

Comment: Yes..I have the admin Privilage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like maybe you downloaded the installer for just the client tools.  Try using the installer from [**this page**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1695) appropriate for your platform (x86, x64, etc).

Comment: Yes, Management Studio is not part of those distributions (actually I can't find it for regular SQL 2008 right now either) but it should still be there from your original install.

Comment: Yes I installed Management Studio...It is working fine...Thnax a lot